# Fast matrix multiplication on sparse matrices of 1's in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to carry out multiply matrices containing a sparse number of `1`s and convert the result into another matrix of `1`s for all values `>=1`. For example:

```
[ 1 1 0 ]   [ 1 0 0 ]    [ 2 0 0 ]    [ 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 ] x [ 1 0 0 ] => [ 0 0 0 ] => [ 0 0 0 ] (output)
[ 0 0 0 ]   [ 0 0 0 ]    [ 0 0 0 ]    [ 0 0 0 ]
```

(These matrices represent equally-weighted digraphs and help to solve some theoretical problems.) So far the simplest strategy I've found is to replace the standard

```
output[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
```

with the bitwise operations taking advantage of the fact that I only have `0`s and `1`s in my input matrices and only need `1`s in the output, like this:

```
void mult(int n, int A[][n], int B[][n], int output[n][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                output[i][j] = output[i][j] | A[i][k] & B[k][j];
}
```

However, this is still pretty slow! For moderately-sized dense matrices (`n>100`), a quick benchmark shows that MATLAB's underlying BLAS subroutine is about 3x faster than my approach above!

What should I do? Without going into cache-level optimizations, the only major step I can think of making is to represent these matrices as arrays of only the coordinates of `1`s to take advantage of any sparseness, but even in the dense case, it seems that there's something I can do to speed this up.

Comment: What's the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: @user3386109 It's around 10^3.

Comment: That's bigger than expected. I was going to suggest preprocessing the rows of A and the columns of B into `int`s. Then it takes a single `&` to compute each `output[i][j]`. With n = 1000 bits per row/col, you would need 32 `int`s for each row/col, and each `output[i][j]` would require 32 `&`s

Comment: It's important to structure the loops so that matrix elements are accessed in memory address order, to the degree possible. Otherwise you get cache misses, which slow things down.

Comment: With n=1000, I don't think your trick of using bitwise operations is going to offset the penalty of naive O(n^3) matrix multiplication compared to BLAS's highly optimized sub-cubic routine.

Comment: Use all of the bits in a word and you'll get a 32-64x speedup.

Comment: @Imran: All BLAS implementations of the matrix-matrix product are still O(n^3).  Only the constant of the n^3 term is much smaller.  Strassen and friends is not used by any BLAS implementation.

Comment: Interesting. I just assumed otherwise. Some good info [here](http://www.quora.com/What-algorithm-does-BLAS-use-for-matrix-multiplication-Of-all-the-considerations-e-g-cache-popular-instruction-sets-Big-O-etc-which-one-turned-out-to-be-the-primary-bottleneck) and [here](http://www.quora.com/Does-the-LAPACK-GEMM-general-matrix-matrix-multiplication-routine-use-the-Strassen-O-N-2-8-algorithm-or-the-traditional-O-N-3-technique).

Comment: Numerical stability of Strassen can be achieved ( http://www.math.washington.edu/~dumitriu/fmm_arxiv.pdf).  But loosing cache efficiency is still an issue (and probably loosing the Top500 qualification).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go to cache level optimization.  It actually is not that hard.  You can use the [C code from ulmBLAS](http://apfel.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/~lehn/sghpc/gemm/page02/index.html).

In your case it should not be necessary to implement the micro kernel in assembler.  It should be sufficient to modify lines 135-143 according to your implementation.

Edit: In addition, storing/compressing 32/64 bits in a int/long as suggested by nwellnhof should give you a further performance boost.  Still, using a blocked (cache friendly) algorithm is the necessary condition for an efficient matrix-matrix product.

Answer (score 0):

For large matrices with few non-zero values, you will be better off mapping (x,y) coordinates to value in say a std::vector. This if nothing else should lessen the number of cache misses when looking up values.

You can also add optimizations like short circuiting cases where either a whole row or whole column are zeros.